# If I want to set aside range of addresses to be assigned to servers

Tags: windows, ip-address, ipv4, system-administration, network-service

I am assigning the DHCP IPv4 addresses and I would like to set aside 5 addresses for future servers, will that mean that I have to have the end IP address as 192.168.1.249?

[screenchot of the range I currently assigned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7nTm.png)

[DHCP description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ur3u.png)

Answer (score 0):

If your 5 servers will have static IP configured, Yes it's enough to shrink last ip-range to `192.168.1.249`

If your 5 servers will be configured with `DHCP` too, you need to leave it to `192.168.1.254` and then create static reserves for them. ( on DHCP server window)

- Folder `Reservation` > second button `New reservation`
- Fill all data, if you don't know what mac will have each one, you can invent like `00-00-00-00-00-01` until you know them

[Tutorial with images](https://www.itingredients.com/configure-dhcp-server-reservation-windows-server-2012-r2/)